# Большая задержка перед проигрыванием mp3 с сервера с помощью AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

Использую `AVAudioPlayer` для проигрывания *mp3* с сайта. Есть большая задержка, потому что файлы загружаются и затем мутируют в `NSData`. `AVAudioPlayer` с использованием URL у меня не проигрывает аудио - может, делаю что-то не так.

Как можно проигрывать аудио асинхронно (то есть если 10% трека прогрузились, проиграть это 10%, пока грузится остальное)?
Такое было реализовано в приложении VK - у меня аналогичная задача.

Сам код `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
let url = audios.objectForKey("items")![indexPath.row]["url"] as! String
let fileURL = NSURL(string:url)
let soundData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL!)
self.player = try! AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData!)
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
player.volume = 1.0
player.prepareToPlay()
self.player.delegate = self
player.play()
```

P.S. Не привязан к использованию `AVAudioPlayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы проигрываете аудио с сервера, я бы порекомендовал

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: someURL))
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.play()
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже так и решил